# Find Repeated Digits In List with Java

Tags: java, pi

I am working on Pi Finder app.I know there is a lot  of apps about it but i want to do it myself.I did  it with Leibniz formula but it is working very slow because of repeated numbers.I am using lists for storage.Can you help me about find repeated numbers in lists or arrays?

Example
{1,2,5,4,7,6,4,7,6,4,7,....}
I need to find 4,7,6

Comment: If you want to remove duplicates - use a `Set`.

Comment: The phrasing is unclear. Are you searching for duplicate integers in a `List<Integer>` or a `List<int[]>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the duplicate elements by using a `Set` as the accumlator and then utilise `Collections.frequency` to check if a given number occurs more than once within the `List<Integer>` like this:

```
List<Integer> elements = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,5,4,7,6,4,7,6,4,7));
Set<Integer> accumulator = new LinkedHashSet<>(); 
for (Integer number : elements) {
   if(Collections.frequency(elements, number) > 1)
       accumulator.add(number);   
}
```

now the `accumulator` contains:

```
[4, 7, 6]
```

`LinkedHashSet` is utilised here to maintain insertion order. if that is not required then you can use a `HashSet` instead.

or a better performant solution as suggested by JB Nizet:

```
List<Integer> elements = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,5,4,7,6,4,7,6,4,7));
Set<Integer> tempAccumulator = new LinkedHashSet<>();
Set<Integer> resultSet = new LinkedHashSet<>();
for (Integer number : elements) {
     if(!tempAccumulator.add(number))
        resultSet.add(number);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.It is very useful.I forgot answer sorry about that.